# How to check if a the same python script is running in another computer in a small network?

Tags: python, mysql, server

I'm going to distribute my "handy" python script to my co workers in the same department as me. The script works with MySQL database, they are all in the same network as me.

But I don't want the script to run at the same time because it will cause problem with the database.

So I decided that in the distributed script it would check first if there are other of the same script running on other computers in my department, If there aren't any then it would continue to run , it would not run is there are already other same script was running in the other departments computer.

Comment: Maybe this wil help you further. To check if a script is running on a pc use in the command line: Windows: tasklist | FIND "script.py" - Linux: ps aux | grep "script.py"

Comment: That's useful if the script are running on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Python sockets module. You can send Network messages through it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a mutex on the database if it is only able to be handled by a single instance of the script.

It would save you trawling the network constantly looking for an instance of the script running.

Comment: Can you explain more? I actually don't have administrative access to the database.